# Create a vector of empty S4 objects

Tags: r, r-s4

This maybe trivial but I haven't found anything online.
Is it possible to create a vector of empty S4 objects in R?
Something like:

```
s4Vec<-rep(emptyS4Object,10)
```

Thanks

Comment: Vectors can hold only atomic types: logical, integer, real, complex, string or raw. Did you mean a list?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correction. Now that I'm aware that a vector is irrelevant I'll rephrase my question by exchanging vector for list. So, is it possible to create a list of empty S4 objects in R?

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- Not true. Lists and expression objects are also types of vectors. (Try `is.vector(list())` and `is.vector(expression())` to confirm.)

Comment: `replicate()` might work too? (haven't tried it)

Comment: @DavidRobinson *atomic* vectors can hold only one type of data from a few basic choices. Vectors per se can hold whatever mix of data you want, i.e. lists.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
s4Vec <- lapply( rep("yourClass", 10), new )
```

?

Comment: If any of the answers solves your problem, it'd be nice if you'd accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to go with

```
.A <- setClass("A", representation(x="integer"))
a <- list(.A())[rep(1, 100)]
```

which makes a single instance (using the convenient generator returned by `setClass`) and then replicates that object as R would replicate any other object in a list -- the elements of `a` are actually the same instance, marked ready to be duplicated when changed; you can see this from

```
> .Internal(inspect(a))
@4e3bc1d8 19 VECSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=2, tl=0)
  @60b738b8 25 S4SXP g0c0 [OBJ,NAM(2),S4,gp=0x10,ATT] 
  ATTRIB:
[...]
  @60b738b8 25 S4SXP g0c0 [OBJ,NAM(2),S4,gp=0x10,ATT]
```

where `@4e3bc1d8` is the address of the list and `@60b738b8 25 S4SXP g0c0 [OBJ,NAM(2),S4,gp=0x10,ATT]` mark the start of the description of each S4 element, all actually at the same location in memory `@60b738b8` and with the so-called NAMED field set to 2 `NAM(2)`. Note that changing a single element of the list likely triggers a copy of the entire list.

But if each of your "A" objects are meant to represent say a "row" in a traditional data base, then **you should re-think your design** and have "A" represent the entire table and slots represent columns. So you'd just create one "A", rather than many, and populate it's slots with equal-length vectors. This will be memory efficient, and will set you up for efficient vectorized calculations down-stream, rather than iterations.