# vapply fun.value S4

Tags: r, apply, r-s4

I am having a hard time finding what should be my FUN.VALUE of my vapply:

```
> sapply(ind, function(x) typeof(dataset[[x]]))
[1] "S4"
> sapply(ind, function(x) mode(dataset[[x]]))
[1] "S4"
> sapply(ind, function(x) storage.mode(dataset[[x]]))
[1] "S4"
> sapply(ind, function(x) is(dataset[[x]]))
 [,1]          
 [1,] "PlotSetPair" 
 [2,] "envRefClass" 
 [3,] ".environment"
 [4,] "refClass"    
 [5,] "environment" 
 [6,] "refObject"   
 [7,] "AssayData"
```

I have tried the following possibilities without success:

```
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, S4)
Error in vapply(ind, function(x) { : object 'S4' not found
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, "S4")
Error in vapply(ind, function(x) { : values must be type 'character',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'S4'
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, "S4-class")
Error in vapply(ind, function(x) { : values must be type 'character',
but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'S4'
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, S4-class)
Error in vapply(ind, function(x) { : object 'S4' not found
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, PlotSetPair)
Error in vapply(ind, function(x) { : object 'PlotSetPair' not found
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, PlotSetPair())
Error in PlotSetPair() : could not find function "PlotSetPair"
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, seqplots::PlotSetPair())
Error: 'PlotSetPair' is not an exported object from 'namespace:seqplots'
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, seqplots::PlotSetPair)
Error: 'PlotSetPair' is not an exported object from 'namespace:seqplots'
> vapply(ind, function(x){return(dataset[[x]]);}, PlotSetPair-class)
Error in vapply(ind, function(x) { : object 'PlotSetPair' not found
```

Is there a solution or can I use only vapply with primitive types?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16366739/4996248

Comment: You can use `vapply` with non-primitive types, but the result will be a list. You might as well use `lapply` instead, since you will end up with a list anyway.

Comment: This worked for me: `unlist(vapply(ind, function(x) list(dataset[[x]]), c(new("PlotSetPair")))`. Thanks a lot @johnColeman @JDL

Comment: @nicoluca It is an interesting question and doesn't seem to be a duplicate. Perhaps you can turn your comment into an answer to your own question. I'll upvote it if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

`unlist(vapply(ind, function(x) list(dataset[[x]]), c(new("PlotSetPair")))`

The trick was to use `c()` to make it a list and therefore coerce `dataset[[x]]` to `list(dataset[[x]]`. I unlist it then.

Thanks a lot @johnColeman @JDL